# Why does TomEE class loader process not find Hibernate classes from ear/lib?

Tags: hibernate, ear, tomee-7

I build the classic ear application contains the submodule EJB (into jar) and WEB (into war).

I deployed my ear (JAR + WAR) into TomEE and used Hibernate JPA provider. I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/integrator/spi/Integrator
```

Hibernate jars are into the `ear/lib`.
There is the hibernate-core-4.2.16.Final that contains the class `org/hibernate/integrator/spi/Integrator`.

So i think Tomee ClassLoader process doesn't load the class from my ear/lib folder.

Is it Right? If it is, why?

Help please

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't detect it from there as it is not the default assumption where such "global" libraries should be placed. [TomEE reference documentation](https://tomee.apache.org/deploying-in-tomee.html) states:

> Three classloader minimum: a classloader for the ear, one for each ejb-jar, and one for each WAR file.

As we learn from this quote, an EAR application, especially its EAR modules are initialized with their **own** classloader instance very early on container startup, and *before* WAR initialization kicks in with an own classloader.

I guess your EAR module (the one within the jar file) represents the backend-layer module, scanning for Hibernate trying to load related class files. Sadly, it can't "see" them within the scope of it's classloader.

#### Solution

It will work, however, when you put all Hibernate jars (and all transitive dependencies, like *antlr*, *dom4j*, *javassist*, ...) into the global `lib` directory according to the [TomEE directory layout](https://tomee.apache.org/understanding-the-directory-layout.html). This makes much more sense anyway, since thus it can be reused by different parts of your application which can/will be bundled into your EAR deployable or even totally different applications run in the same container. Thereby, *global* jar files will be available in the classpath of the ejb module and thus Hibernate can be brought up on container startup.

Once placed into your container-wide installation, you can than remove the Hibernate jars from being bundled into the `EAR/lib` folder (by declaring it as a *provided* dependency in a `pom.xml` in a Maven project setup).

This will - as a side effect also drastically reduce your EAR bundle size, as the libraries are "global" now. At runtime, you will also observe that the memory footprint we be reduced, as all class files of the Hibernate ORM  will only be loaded once within the container and not multiple times for different EARs or WAR bundles.

Hint(s):

1. When working with TomEE-7, I recommend to upgrade Hibernate to at least version 4.3.11, since with 4.3.x Hibernate JPA support is available for version 2.1 of the specification. Moreover, in case you are free to do so, try to [migrate](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/wiki/Migration-Guides) your application to version Hibernate 5.2.x as it brings a lot of improvements.
2. For a full list of transitive Hibernate dependencies, check the list [for version 4.2.x here](https://mvnrepository.org/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.21.Final) or for [version 4.3.x here](https://mvnrepository.org/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final), Hibernate 5.2.x analogously. You only need to collect/bundle the referenced "Compile Dependencies" and put these into the global TomEE "lib" directory to make things work.
3. Also place the JDBC driver you use in your application within the global `lib` folder.

Hope it helps.